# iText-5.0.1 + Make the border of PdfPTable with dotted line

Tags: java, itext

Is there any way to make the border of a cell with dotted line (e.g _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _) instead of solid line ( e.g ________________ ) in iText-5.0.1????

Answer (score 1):

could you rig something like adding new paragraphs with small height and text="---------"

```
PdfPCell Cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("------"));
Cell.Height = 0.2f;
```

You can also draw the borders yourself using a PdfPCellEvent. There are different layers to add to. See the API here: http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCellEvent.html

Comment: I guess we can't set height for cell?

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested, use a PdfPCellEvent. The code below should get you most of the way there.
[Cell event example.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/implementsPdfPCellEvent.htm) By overriding the cell event, you basically tell iText how you think it should draw its cells. Whenever any cells are added to the table they'll follow your rules.

```
 class CustomCell implements PdfPCellEvent {
 public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect,
                   PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
                   PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
                   cb.setLineDash(new float[] {3.0f, 3.0f}, 0);           
                   cb.stroke();
          }
 }

 public class Main {

         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
             Document document = new Document();
             PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
             document.open();
             CustomCell border = new CustomCell();

             PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
             PdfPCell cell;

             for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
               cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("test"));              
               cell.setCellEvent(border);
               table.addCell(cell);
             }

             document.add(table);
             document.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: I've following error message by E-Clipse when I tried your code..."No enclosing instance of type pdf is accessible....." Any idea what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Cell underlined with dashes:

```
public class UnderlinedCell implements PdfPCellEvent {

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.setLineWidth(0.5f);
        canvas.setLineDash(3f, 3f);
        canvas.moveTo(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
        canvas.lineTo(position.getRight(), position.getBottom());

        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfPCell Border1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
            Border1.Border = 0;
            Border1.VerticalAlignment = 3;
            Border1.FixedHeight = 5F;
            Border1.PaddingLeft = -5;
            Border1.PaddingRight = -5;
            Border1.PaddingBottom = -5;
            Border1.PaddingTop = -5;
```